# Global component in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony1

I am currently implementing the navigation of the website (multilevel menu, having current page highlighted).
As navigation part will be included for virtually all modules, I first made it a global partial.
But logic for selection of "current page" is quite complicated in some situations, I am thinking of using a component for the navigation.

The problem is that symfony allows to have global partials, but not global components. 
So is there a "nice symfony way" to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't a mechanism for this as such. I usually end up creating an empty module called default and putting stuff like that in there.

Comment: you at least should avoid using "global" as module name, it's reserved word for global partials.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with:

```
<?php include_component('someModule', 'navigationComponent') ?>
```

... where you store it in some general module (e.g. "general") and call it wherever you want, including your layouts. Isn't that global enough?

Answer (score 0):

This is your solution:

Create the yourproject/yourapp/templates/_globalpartial.php with this content:

```
<?php include_component('yourmodule', 'yourcomponent'); ?>
```

And use this globalpartial.php in yourproject/yourapp/templates/layout.php